# This branch is x commits ahead of xy:master

Tags: git, github

I [forked](https://github.com/adrianmihalko/brands) a project on GitHub, started pushing PR's (each under different branch). Everything was good. Then I saw that my :master is X commits behind so I wanted to update to current upstream state.

I tried:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/home-assistant/brands.git
git pull upstream master
git push --force-with-lease origin master
```

[image]

I get:

> This branch is 4 commits ahead of home-assistant:master.

Now each time I create new PR it adds extra commits:

[image]

Great. I found many similar questions and answers here, but none seem to be working (fetch, reset --hard origin/master).

Is there any way to fix this, or I should delete the fork and start over?

Comment: Yes, there is definitely a way to fix this. But we need to see the real history. Can we see a `git log --graph --decorate --oneline` of the last 10 commits or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd need to see `git log --graph --decorate --oneline` to be sure, but here's what likely happened.

`git pull upstream master` is really a `git fetch upstream` and a `git merge upstream/master`. As with any merge, it will leave behind merge commits. That's what you're seeing.

These merges are unnecessary. Unlike merging a feature branch, these update merges are of no interest to future coders on this project. And they get in the way.

You can get rid of them by instead of merging on top of upstream/master, rebase on top of upstream/master. `git rebase upstream/master`. Instead of merging, your local commits will be rewritten on top of the latest upstream/master. Existing unnecessary merges will be eliminated.

I recommend rebasing for all pulls. You can configure your Git to do this with `git config --global pull.rebase merges`. This will rebase, but preserve existing merges.

Finally, to avoid this situation in the future, don't to work on your master branch. Keep master clean. Do all your work in [feature branches](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow), use that as your PR, and delete the feature branch afterward. This will avoid many problems.

---

To illustrate, here's what "diverged by X commits" looks like.

```
upstream
A - B - C - G - H - I [master]

origin
          G - H - I [upstream/master]
         /  
A - B - C - D - E [master]
```

And after you `git pull upstream master`...

```
$ git pull upstream master

upstream
A - B - C - G - H - I [master]

origin
          G - H - I [upstream/master]
         /         \
A - B - C - D - E - M [master]
```

Note the merge. To eliminate this, rebase on top of upstream/master.

```
$ git rebase upstream/master

upstream
A - B - C - G - H - I [master]

origin

A - B - C - G - H - I [upstream/master]
                     \
                      D1 - E1 [master]
```

Now your history is nice and linear as if you were working on top of the latest master all the time.

Finally, this work should be done in a feature branch. That would look like this.

```
upstream
A - B - C - G - H - I [master]

origin
          G - H - I [upstream/master]
         /  
A - B - C [master]
         \
          D - E [feature]
```

Updating master is now a simple fast-forward.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull upstream master

upstream
A - B - C - G - H - I [master]

origin
                      [upstream/master]
A - B - C - G - H - I [master]
         \
          D - E [feature]
```

And you can rebase your feature branch on top of master (or skip a step and rebase directly on top of upstream/master).

```
$ git checkout feature
$ git rebase master

upstream
A - B - C - G - H - I [master]

origin
                      [upstream/master]
A - B - C - G - H - I [master]
                     \
                      D1 - E1 [feature]
```

Comment: I'll try to keep with you, but it's hard. Git log before: https://pastebin.com/raw/72DTQhCX, after $ git rebase upstream/master: https://pastebin.com/raw/kx1V2AU0. Now I can't push, because "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind".

Comment: @Adrian Git is hard, but it's worth it. `git push --force-with-lease origin master` should have done it. This situation is what [`--force-with-lease`](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/force-with-lease/) is for, safely pushing after a rebase. Has anyone else pushed to origin/master in the meantime? Can you do a `git fetch origin` to update your view of origin and then show `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all`? I'd need to see where origin/master is.

Comment: it's really hard if you go into details. I need to start learning. Now it's seem to be good: https://pastebin.com/raw/F47MnNkE

Comment: @Adrian  I'm glad you got it going. The details are important. Git is not a tool you can use by memorizing a sequence of commands. It's very tempting, but it's like trying to untie a knot by yanking on it; it just makes it worse. For example, after your `git log` you did a `git push` for no reason, it could have made things worse.